# Folium Heatmap With Time for COVID 19

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap, folium

I am trying to create a Heatmap movie for the confirmed cases of Covid 19.

My dataset is a `pd.dataFrame` with columns `Date`, `Latitude`, `Longitude`, `Confirmed`.

My issue is that I do not know how to input the Confirmed value as an input in the `Folium.plugin.HeatmapWithTime`.

I tried using:

```py
new_map = folium.Map(location=[0, 0], tiles= "cartodbpositron",min_zoom=2, zoom_start=2, max_zoom=3)

df['Lat'] = df['Lat'].astype(float)
df['Long'] = df['Long'].astype(float)

Confirmed_df = df[['Lat', 'Long','Confirmed']]

hm = plugins.HeatMapWithTime(Confirmed_df,auto_play=True,max_opacity=0.8)
hm.add_to(new_map)

new_map
```

df looks like:

```
Date                     LAT           LONG    Confirmed 
2020/04/26             48.847306     2.433284   6500
2020/04/26             48.861935     2.441292   4800      
2020/04/26             48.839644     2.655109   9000   
2020/04/25             48.924351     2.386369   12000      
2020/04/25             48.829872     2.376677   0
```

Comment: Please, provide full code and data. Thanks.

Comment: Heatmap works with locations and dates. `Confirmed` column could be useful for other kinds of graphs.

Comment: Then it wouldn't make any sense to do a HeatMap movie because there will be only on observation for each date for each location right?

Answer (score 4):

You should pre-process data before input to HeatMapWithTime() function. The Folium [document](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/plugins.html) and [example](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/HeatMapWithTime.ipynb) here are helpful.

In your case, the input should be a list of [lat, lng, weight], you should use Confirmed column as a weight. The first thing, you need normalize 'Confirmed' values to (0, 1].

```py
df['Confirmed'] = df['Confirmed'] / df['Confirmed'].sum()
```

Then, you can preprocess like this:

```py
df['Date'] = df['Date'].sort_values(ascending=True)
data = []
for _, d in df.groupby('Date'):
   data.append([[row['lat'], row['lng'], row['Confirmed']] for _, row in d.iterrows()])
```

Finally, use data to input to function HeatMapWithTime() as you did:

```py
hm = plugins.HeatMapWithTime(data, auto_play=True,max_opacity=0.8)
hm.add_to(new_map)
new_map
```